# Computing an exponential of matrix via cayley-hamilton

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, matrix-exponential

I want to compute the exponential $e^{At}$ of
$$A=\left( \begin{matrix} 5&2 \\ 0&5 \end{matrix}\right)$$

via Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

So, the formula is:

$$e^{At}=\alpha_0I+\alpha_1A$$

In order to find $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$, I have to solve the following system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}
e^{5t}=\alpha_0+5\alpha_1\\[1ex]
te^{5t}=\alpha_1
\end{cases}$$

I don't really know if I formulated the system of equations correctly, because when I compute this in MATLAB I got a different result in respect to the one given by the MATLAB function `expm`:

> > A=[5 2;0 5];
> >
> > syms t
> >
> > expm(A*t) %computing by MATLAB function
> >
> > % Computing by Cayley-Hamilton:
> >
> > B=[exp(5*t);t*exp(5*t)];
> >
> > C=[1 5;0 1];
> >
> > X=C\B;
> >
> > exponential=X(1,1)*eye(2)+X(2,1)*A

The results are:

By MATLAB:

[ exp(5*t), 2*t*exp(5*t); 0,     exp(5*t)]

By 'what I did'

[ exp(5*t) - 4*t*exp(5*t),            5*t*exp(5*t); 0, exp(5*t) - 4*t*exp(5*t)]

They are different. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you do not need matlab or anything else. The diagonal part and the nilpotent part commute; you need to exponentiate $5I,$ then exponentiate $N = A - 5I.$ Then take the product, in either order. .... Did not notice the $t.$ Switch to exp of $5tI,$ then $Nt = At - 5tI$

Comment: The equations you’ve written down are correct, so you’re botching something in MATLAB. Try solving for the coefficients by hand and see what you get.

Comment: it was the `X=C\B`. Changing this to `X=inv(C)*B` leads to the right result..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of relying on a memorized formula, try working directly with what the Cayley-Hamilton theorem tells you.

Since $A$ is upper-triangular, we see immediately that it has a repeated eigenvalue of $5$, so by C-H we know that $(A-5I)^2=0$. In other words, $A$ can be decomposed into the sum of the diagonal matrix $5I$ and the nilpotent matrix $N=A-5I$, with $N^2=0$. As Will Jagy points out in his comment, these two matrices commute, so $$\exp(tA)=\exp(5tI)\exp(tN).$$ Since $N$ is nilpotent, the series for its exponential gets truncated after a couple of terms, giving $\exp(tN)=I+tN$. Multiplying by a scalar multiple of the identity matrix amounts to scalar multiplication, so putting it all together we get $$\exp(tA)=e^{5t}(I+tN)=\pmatrix{e^{5t}&2te^{5t}\\0&e^{5t}},$$ just as MATLAB computed.

*Update:* To relate this to the method in the paper you cite, note that $\alpha_0I+\alpha_1A=(\alpha_0+5\alpha_1)I + \alpha_1N$, which yields the system $$\begin{align}\alpha_0+5\alpha_1&=e^{5t}\\\alpha_1&=te^{5t},\end{align}$$ as you had, with solution $$\begin{align}\alpha_0&=e^{5t}(1-5t)\\\alpha_1&=te^{5t}.\end{align}$$ It would appear that you’ve made an arithmetic error somewhere, since you’ve got $(1-4t)$ instead. Note that the second equation in this system is what you’d get by differentiating the first, as per the note on repeated eigenvalues at the end of the paper.

P.S.: More generally, for a $2\times2$ matrix $A$ with repeated eigenvalue $\lambda$, we have $$\begin{align}e^{tA}&=e^{\lambda t}(I+tN)\\&=e^{\lambda t}(I+tA-\lambda tI)\\&=(1-\lambda t)e^{\lambda t}I+te^{\lambda t}A,\end{align}$$ so $\alpha_0=(1-\lambda t)e^{\lambda t}$ and $\alpha_1=te^{\lambda t}$.

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer but I want to compute the exponential by the $\alpha$ coeficients ( I need these coefficients for my application)... So, I've tried to use the "formulas" (5) and (6) from page four, and the ''formula'' from page five from this pdf 

http://web.mit.edu/2.151/www/Handouts/CayleyHamilton.pdf 

But maybe I formulated the system of equations uncorrectly and I just cant see it. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: well, forget it, I took another example with repetead eigenvalues and this time my computations yielded an result which is equal to the one given by MATLAB...

Answer (score 1):

A way to compute the $\alpha$-coefficients is to note that $$\frac {d}{dt}e^{At}= \dot{\alpha}_0I+\dot{\alpha}_1 A=Ae^{At}=\alpha_0 A+\alpha_1 A^2.$$ This is a first-order system of ODEs which can be solved to yield the $\alpha$'s.

---

I decided I should fill in the steps above, and in particular do so in a way that takes advantage of the structure of $A$. As noted, the Cayley-Hamilton theorem implies that $e^{At}=\alpha_0I+\alpha_1 A$ for some $\alpha_0,\alpha_1$. But $A=5I+N$ where $N^2=0$, so we may just as well write the above as $e^{At}=\alpha I+\beta N$ for some $\alpha,\beta$. Then $$\frac {d}{dt}e^{At}= \dot{\alpha}I+\dot{\beta} N=Ae^{At}=(N+5I)(\alpha I+\beta N)=5\alpha I+(\alpha+5\beta)N,$$ which upon taking matrix elements yields the first-order ODEs $\dot{\alpha}=5\alpha, \dot{\beta}=\alpha+5\beta$. Since $e^{At}|_0=I = \alpha(0)I+\beta(0) N$, we have the initial conditions $\alpha(0)=1$ and $\beta(0)=0$. The system of ODES is then readily solved and yields $$e^{At}=\alpha(t)I+\beta(t)N=e^{5t}I+t e^{5t}N$$ which is the solution found by MATLAB.